# Do unenchanted books not stack with regular books?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I have been doing a lot of AFK Fishing, looking for some mending books. And now, with 1.14 giving us the Grindstone that can remove enchantments, I've been using that so I can get some more books easily, for future enchantment. However, I've noticed that I have 2 stacks of books, and they won't stack together.

I know I have books from two sources: I have created some in a crafting bench/looting libraries, and some are from unenchanting them.

Is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out - yes.

I had 2 stacks; one with 7 books, the other with 4. I enchanted one of each, then when I unenchanted them, they joined the 7 book stack. So I had a stack of 8, and a stack of 3.

I then crafted a new book, and it joined the 3 book stack.

After showing Advanced tooltips (<kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>) one stack had the tag `minecraft:book`, the other had `minecraft:book NBT: 1 tag(s)`.

At this point I don't know if this is intentional or a bug.

---

User [54D](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/79435/54d) has pointed out that this has/will be fixed in a later version:

> Per [MC-148476](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-148476) this will be fixed in 1.14+

Comment: Per [MC-148476](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-148476) this will be fixed in 1.14.1+